# Unbound (with PiHole): Where is root.hints?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, apt, pihole, unbound

I installed unbound to use with pihole with this instruction:
https://docs.pi-hole.net/guides/dns/unbound/

It says that I don't need to download root.hints, if I use apt install. Because it would download root.hints automatically with the "dependency dns-root-data" (whatever that means?).

> If you are installing unbound from a package manager, it should
> install the root.hints file automatically with the dependency
> dns-root-data. The root hints will then be automatically updated by
> your package manager.

If I now

```
sudo apt install unbound
```

and then

```
ls -al /var/lib/unbound/
```

there is no root.hints

Shouldn't it be there, because "apt install unbound" has downloaded it automatically?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The article talks about installing on Debian, using Debian's `apt` package manager, so it is referencing the [dns-root-data](https://packages.debian.org/bullseye/dns-root-data) package that's also available through apt. In other words, it is *not* part of the 'unbound' package – it is installed *together with* the 'unbound' package.

As this is a generic package meant to be used by various DNS software, it installs files into a generic directory (still beneath /usr/share) and not into an Unbound-specific location. `apt-file` says that root.hints can be found at:

```
/usr/share/dns/root.hints
```

Note that this is Debian-specific. Unbound actually includes a *compiled-in* list of root nameservers, and on other distributions it will run even without an external hints file. (However, unbundling is part of Debian's packaging policy.)

Comment: thank a lot! I actually have this file (I use Ubuntu 20.04.2 server). It is an older version (May 2019) than the current version (May 2021). I did upgrade and dist-upgrade with reboot but the file did not update. Can unbound access the file anyway and how would this file be updated?

Comment: I just saw that the package dns-root-data has the current version "2019052802" (May 2019). Therefore my ubuntu already has the newest version until the package will get an update soon, I guess